# TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined when performing delete operation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I have go through the other solution which are available in stackoverflow bt it didnt work for me.So please someone suggest me what to do in my case.
 In my case when i am performing delete operation its giving error on console,bt remember its not reflecting on deleting operation,its working fine.I just want to remove or solve this error.

Here is my console error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
at ChildScope.$scope.deleteJob (uploadController.js:454)
at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12474)
```

Here is my code at line no. 454:

```
//delete JD
    $scope.deleteJob = function (fileName) {
      $scope.loadingJobs = true;
      _deleteFile(fileName, AppConstants.docType.JOBDESCRIPTION);
       //line no.454
      if ((jdService.getjdFileName() === fileName) || ((jdService.getjdFileName().concat(".xml") === fileName))) { //line no.454
        $scope.isjdDeleted = false;
        jdService.setisSelected(false);
      }

    };
```

Here is my method where i am getting jdName from UI :

```
jdService.setjdFileName(fileName);
```

and here is my service where i have defined my jdFileName methods:

```
var jdService = [
    function() {
        var jdFileName;
        return {
        getjdFileName: function () {
            return jdFileName;
        },
        setjdFileName: function(value) {
            jdFileName = value;
        },
```

Please suggest me what to do in that,Thanks

Comment: `jdService.getjdFileName()` returns `undefined`

Comment: ok,so how can i handle this here?

Comment: post code of `jdService.getjdFileName()`

Comment: var jdFileName;
            return {
            getjdFileName: function () {
                return jdFileName;
            },
            setjdFileName: function(value) {
                jdFileName = value;
            },

Comment: Thank you @MaximShoustin for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the expression in `if` to:

`if ((jdService.getjdFileName() === fileName) || (((jdService.getjdFileName() || '' ).concat(".xml") === fileName)))`

then this part `(jdService.getjdFileName() || '' )` will evaluate either to the value that is returned by `jdService.getjdFileName()` or, if that value is falsy, than to the empty string (''). This way you can ensure that concat() will always be called on a string.

Comment: Thank you @marekful for your reply

Comment: Thank you @marekful its working now there is no error coming in console and delete operation is also working fine.thank you for your solutions.